# How can I forward and capture all traffic from a device (mobile, or PC) from another network?

Tags: network, proxy, monitoring, fiddler

Let's say Mobile device A sits on Network A, and I want to monitor their HTTPS traffic remotely, how might I go about doing this? I know that locally, on the same network, a proxy debugging tool can help (Charles proxy, Fiddler, etc.). But how about if I want to do this remotely?

I have full access to Mobile device A and can have it configured as needed.
Is it possible to setup a remote proxy (say a Charles Proxy instance) and then configure my
mobile devices or PCs on one network to go through that remote proxy?

Comment: Use a VPN that you can access remotely.

Comment: If you have a device a network A which is able to capture traffic at network A then the question is not how to *forward and capture* but how to *capture and forward*. The first (capture) you do already with the device and for forwarding the captured traffic you could use whatever connectivity you have to the device: SSH, VPN, ... . But this is not actually a security question.